# Question about HttpWebRequest class in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I would like to know two things about the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
objRequest.Method = "POST";
objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
myWriter.Write(strPost);
```

Here are my two questions:
- What is exactly a stream?
- The line myWriter.Write sends an Http Packet with the post information or to do that i have to use a method of HttpWebRequest class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) is the usual .NET equivalent of a buffer.  It's also almost always used when doing any sort of IO, be it [files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx), [pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream.aspx), [network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx).  Usually to work with a stream you use either [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) or [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx).

Your method should be sending a packet correctly.  To read a response you would do a similar operation with `GetResponseStream`.

Comment: Then the Write method of the stream sends the post information to the url... Now clear.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A stream in .NET can be regarded as kind of a buffer.
It is used in file/http/memory IO

Answer (score 1):

The stream in this case is a buffer which will be sent over network. This buffer is sent when you use `GetResponse` function

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream%28VS.80%29.aspx